# Use sphinx within a serverless model

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, serverless, docutils, serverless-architecture

I am currently using sphinx to automatically generate my documentation site from ReStructuredText files within a bitbucket repo.

This is of course all managed/hosted internally but I have been thinking more and more about whether I could switch this out for a more serverless model, using FaaS to generate the site and then a cloud based site hosting for the actual hosting (e.g S3 static site hosting).

I was wondering whether it was possible to use sphinx in a programmatic way (e.g within a AWS Lambda or Azure Function)?

Thanks,
John

Comment: As someone who doesn't know very much about serverless models, AWS Lambda, Azure Function etc, I wonder what you mean by "use sphinx in a programmatic way". As opposed to "non-programmatic"?

Comment: Perhaps bad choice of phrase, I mean call and use within code rather than from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of executing [`sphinx-build`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-build.html) from the command line, you can generate output by using a [`sphinx.application.Sphinx`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx) object directly.

A basic example:

```
import os
from sphinx.application import Sphinx

# Main arguments 
srcdir = "/path/to/source"
confdir = srcdir
builddir = os.path.join(srcdir, "_build")
doctreedir = os.path.join(builddir, "doctrees")
builder = "html"

# Create the Sphinx application object
app = Sphinx(srcdir, confdir, builddir, doctreedir, builder)

# Run the build
app.build()
```