# Import sphinx module into python

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

I would like to serve on a flask server an html page with *reStructuredText* using the sphinx *readthedocs* theme, **rendered on-the-fly** from an `rst` file.

How can I import sphinx as a python module, and then use it together with the readthedocs theme and the input `rst` string to obtain a string with the HTML rendered content?

This seems to be a standard task, but I have not found any example of such behaviour online. In particular, I would prefer to not first render it on the OS and then read the rendered html file into python, but to directly do this HTML python.

What I have so far using `docutils` is

```
from docutils import core
from docutils.writers.html4css1 import Writer

def make_doc(raw_rst):
    _w = Writer()
    return core.publish_string(raw_rst, writer=_w)
```

and I would like to have the output HTML using the *readthedocs* theme.

If possible without a hack, I would also prefer to replace the used `docutils` by `sphinx`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49222967/407651.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this at least tell me that what I want to do is not officially supported. I try to clarify my question using some pseudocode.